# After conversion string to float if instruction crazy?

Tags: android, string, if-statement

These are my beginnings in android and programming :-)

In my android application convey the calculation (converted to string) to the next activity in which it will replace the string to a float and do an if statement. On the basis of the float a corresponding message appears in the TextView . The program seems to work but the messages seem to be random.

The code in the first activity Menu:

```
buttonNextMetric.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Menu.this, NextMetric.class);


          intent.putExtra("ace", ace.getText().toString());

           startActivity(intent);
```

The code in the activity NextMetric:

```
        textpochwala = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNextPochwala);


        try {
         float g = Float.valueOf(nextmsac.trim());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.err.println(""+ nfe.getMessage());
        }
        if (g <=10) {
            textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala10); 
        }
        else if (g>10 && g<=15) {
            textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala15);  
        }
        else if (g>15 && g<=20) {
            textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala20); 
        }
        else if (g>20 && g <=25) {
            textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala25); 
        }
        else if (g>25) {
            textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala30); 
        }
```

code strings.xml:

```
<string name="pochwala10"> A < / string>
<string name="pochwala15"> B < / string>
<string name="pochwala20"> C </ string>
<string name="pochwala25"> D </ string>
<string name="pochwala30"> E </ string>
```

It seems that the result of g> 25 message E (OK ), 20 < g <25 message D ( OK) g <20 message A. Why ?
Message B and C does not appear.
What is wrong?

On emulator everything works fine. It doesn't work on the phone.

Comment: Have you tried to log or debug the value of g?

Comment: debuger show only warn: `11-09 08:44:20.759: INFO/ActivityManager(2277): Starting: Intent { cmp=kesser.Nurkowy_Kalkulator_SAC_Pro/.NextMetric (has extras) } from pid 17272
11-09 08:44:21.079: WARN/System.err(17272): null
11-09 08:44:21.360: INFO/ActivityManager(2277): Displayed kesser.Nurkowy_Kalkulator_SAC_Pro/.NextMetric: +486ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `float g` inside of `try/catch` block but trying to use it outside. This is probably you have another `g` property at your class definition and you are referencing to that.

Anyway, use below code and check if it solves your problem.

```
String nextmsac = getIntent().getStringExtra("ace");

try {
    float g = Float.valueOf(nextmsac.trim());

    if (g <= 10) {
        textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala10);
    } else if (g > 10 && g <= 15) {
        textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala15);
    } else if (g > 15 && g <= 20) {
        textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala20);
    } else if (g > 20 && g <= 25) {
        textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala25);
    } else if (g > 25) {
        textpochwala.setText(R.string.pochwala30);
    }

} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.err.println("" + nfe.getMessage());
    textpochwala.setText("error on converting nextmsac to float!: " + nextmsac);
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code works almost fine. Now problem is with converting string to float. When result of calculation is for example 20 textpochwala is ok, when 20,55 i get nfe "error on converting nextmsac to float!: " + 0,55". Debuger say "11-09 11:04:15.813: WARN/System.err(20526): null".

Comment: That is a format issue. try with 20.55. (use dot not comma). Also always format strings before converting to decimals. Read more about DecimalFormat